# How to search the text using the string wild card php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search the following text if it contains the specific link:

```
this my test text and it ontains the link to http://example.com/abc/files and http://example.com/def/files
```

I want that if I search for the link `http://example.com/*/files`, it should show me the text.

I tried this code but no result:

```
if (preg_match("/http://example.com/i", $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
{
     // Code Here
}
```

Comment: use `#` as delimiters instead of `/` and it will work.

Comment: my question is that how i can use the wild card to search for example anything can come in place of asterisk http://example.com/*/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Escape `/`

   ```
   if (preg_match("/http:\/\/example.com/i", $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
   ```
2. Use `#` instead of `/`

   ```
   if (preg_match("#http://example.com#i", $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
   ```

---

Also to use `*`, you need `.` in Regular Expression, so like this:

```
if (preg_match("#http://example.com/.*/files#i", $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
```

But be sure that simple wild card will match `http://example.com/abc/files and http://example.com/def/files` from your string. Since, you are trying to match any character(s) between `http://example.com/` and `/files`. So, in this case, it finds the first instance and the last instance. Trying to match all in-between! To match only the first instance, use `.*?`. So you have to insert two extra symbols.

Comment: my question is that how i can use the wild card to search for example anything can come in place of asterisk example.com*/files

Comment: @Saqib Hmm. Updated at the same time!

Comment: it worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this, don't use `.*` it match result as `http://example.com/abc/files and http://example.com/def/files` use `[^/]+` or `.*?` instead

```
$content = 'this my test text and it ontains the link to http://example.com/abc/files and http://example.com/def/files';

if(preg_match("#http://example.com/[^/]+/files#i", $content, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
    # http://example.com/abc/files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion other than using regular expressions is `fnmatch()` since that can do match checks on strings as well. Supports shell wildcards

http://php.net/fnmatch

`if (fnmatch("*http://example.com/*/files*", $content)) {}`

There may be limitations though such as a character limit (4096? Since it's normally used on file names) and not being supported in Windows.